# A rectangular pig pen is built against an existing brick fence. $24$ m of fencing was used to enclose $70$ m$^2$. Find the dimensions of the pen

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, problem-solving

A rectangular pig pen is built against an existing brick fence. $24$ m of fencing was used to enclose $70$ m$^2$. Find the dimensions of the pen.

If $2L+2W=24$ and $LW=70$

$2L+2W=24$ to $2L=24-2W$ to $L=12-W$

Substitute the answer into: $W(12-W)=70$ to $12W-W^2=70$ to $W^2-12W+70=0$

Quadratic formula with $a=1, b=-12$ and $c=70$ we get $\frac{12 \pm \sqrt{-136}}{2}$ and I cannot seem to go further than this. What can I do now?

If you have another way of solving this, I'd appreciate it if you'd share it with me too.

Ok I found a way to solve this.

$L+2W=24$ and $LW=70$

$L=24$-$2W$

Substitute into = $W(24$-$2W$)=$70$

$-2W^2$+$24W$-$70$=$0$

$W^2$-$12w$+$35$=$0$

W is 7 or 5.

So, $L$=$24-$2$\cdot $7

$L$=$10$

Or

$L$=$24-$2$\cdot $5

$L$=$14$

Answer: $7$ m by $10$ m or $5$ m and $14$ m.

Comment: Its against a brick fence on one side

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, it is.

Comment: If it's against a brick well you don't need to use any fencing for the side.  Your perimeter includes both fencing are brick so $2W + 2L =\text{fencing} + \text{brick wall}= 24+\text{however much of the brick wall you choose to use}$.  HINT: make a better equation than the one I did.

Comment: Your answer would work just as well as if the farmer were building it in the middle of a field (which is impossible as the ideal shape is a square-- well actually a circle-- and $6^2=36 < 70$-- [and if he made a circle $\pi r^2=\pi \times (\frac {Circumference}{2\pi})^2=\frac{144}\pi < 70$]).  You need to work the brick wall into this.

Comment: @fleablood This is supposed to be in the shape of a rectangle actually. Not a circle.  I'm sorry but I am so lost right now. 2W+2L=24+?

Comment: @Ibti No, $2W+2L=24$ does not correctly model your problem.  You need two "arms" of the fence to extend out from the brick wall, but you only need one stretch of fence to connect the two arms.  The brick wall connects the base of the two arms and doesn't require any fencing.

Comment: Think of it this way.   The brick wall will act as one of the sides.  So you only need the fencing for $3$ of the $4$ sides.  You don't have $24 = Perimeter = 2W+2L$.  You have $24 = Part\ of\ the\ Perimeter = 3\ out\ of\ the\ 4\ sides=???????$.

Comment: Sorry about the circle and square stuff.  I can see in hindsight it'd be confusing.  But the point is you need to take the brick wall into acount.  It is one of the sides.  So you either have $2W + 2L = Perimeter = 24 + \text{the brick wall side}$ or $24 = Fencing = \text{the sum of 3 of the 4 sides}$

Comment: Hint.   We will use the brick wall for either the length or the width of one side of the pen.  It doesn't matter which variable we use.  Let say one Width, $W$, of the pen will be the brick wall.... so.....

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Draw a picture of the pen.   Mark the side against the brick wall as $x$.  Mark the side opposite the brick wall as $x$ (it's a rectangle so that side opp the wall is equal).  Mark the other two sides $y$ (its a rectangle so the other two sides are equal).  Now.  What is the proper formula for you $24$ feet of fencing (that covers the side opposite the wall and the two other sides).

Comment: @fleablood 2L+2W=24+ $\frac{3}{4}$ ?

Comment: @Ibti: $L+2W=24$ because, as everyone is saying, you need fencing for only three sides, the fourth side is the brick fence.

Comment: @Vasili Thank you! I was about to add this.

Comment: Nobody has remarked that the fact that the wall is with bricks has not been exploited. Had it been in straw or sticks, would the answer have been the same. And I sign;  :):):) ? Hi, Walt !

Comment: @fleablood I truly appreciate your efforts with the hints! Thank you so much to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

We are told that a rectangular pig pen is built against a wall.  That means three sides of the rectangle are bounded by a fence, while the fourth side of the pen is bounded by a wall.  [image: rectangular_pen_with_one_side_bounded_by_a_wall]

In the diagram, the thick side represents the wall, while the thin sides represent the fence.  We are told that $24~\text{m}$ of fencing are used.  Hence,
$$24~\text{m} = l + 2w \tag{1}$$
We are told that the area of the rectangle is $70~\text{m}^2$.  Hence,
$$70~\text{m}^2 = lw \tag{2}$$
Solve equation $1$ for $l$.  Substitute the resulting expression in the equation for the area to obtain a quadratic equation in $w$.  Solve it for $w$.  Since $w$ represents the width of the pen, discard any solutions for $w$ that are not positive.  Substitute your value(s) for $w$ into the equation you obtained for $l$ to find the corresponding value for $l$.

Comment: I really needed a vivid mental picture of the question after being confused. Thank you truly much!

Comment: Your revised solution is correct.